# GLM matrix multiply vector gives incorrect results

Tags: c++, glm-math

```
glm::fmat4 m(0.001716f, 0.00001f, 0.0f, -0.545988f,
    0.0f, 0.001725f, 0.0f, -0.408158f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, -0.000029f, 0.031473f);
glm::fvec4 v(320.5f, 240.5f, 781.762634f, 1.0f);
glm::fvec4 result = m * v;
printf("result = (%f, %f, %f, %f)\n", result.x, result.y, result.z, result.w);
```

The code above gives:

```
result = (0.549978, 0.418067, -0.000029, -1054.882324)
```

The same calculation done by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0.001716,+0.00001,+0,+-0.545988%7D,%7B0,+0.001725,+0,+-0.408158%7D,+%7B0,+0,+0,+-1%7D,+%7B0,+0,+-0.000029,+0.031473%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B320.5%7D,+%7B240.5%7D,+%7B781.762634%7D,+%7B1%7D%7D):

```
(0.006395
0.0067045
-1
0.00880188)
```

Why? Am I understanding something wrong? If it's relevant, I'm using Visual Studio 2015, 64-bit built target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing `A*b` in one and `Transpose[A]*b` in another.

Comment: Using glm::transpose(m) instead of m gives expected result. Thank you.